# Performance of Matrix Computation on Android

Tags: android, performance, opencv, matrix

I'm doing matrix computation on Android recently, and I want to improve its performance.

I have implemented matrix multiplication in C++, Java (both in naive way), and OpenCV to do the computation.

As you can see in the chart, it took me 56460 ms, nearly one minute, to do the multiplication of two 1000*1000 matrices. By the way, I'm using LG G2 to do the computation.

It is way more slower than the performance on a PC or so on. I know the computation on mobile phones should be slower than other machines, but I believe the difference shouldn't be that much.

I would like to know if my performance is normal (as a mobile phone). If not, is there any way that I can improve it?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What thread are you performing your computations in?  The main (UI) thread?  Or are you performing them in a background thread?

Comment: In a background thread

Comment: It seems like I have been doing things in the same thread instead of doing in multithreads. However, I don't know how to implement the computation in multi-threads.

Comment: There are a few ways to do it.  If you are using API 3+ you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Otherwise, you would have to extend the Thread class.  AsyncTask is arguably easier as it gives you hooks to enter and leave the task from the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. To my understand, AsyncTask does the work on UI thread. And I have been doing my computation on another thread already. I would like to know if there is a way to do the computation on multithreads. In another word, say if I have 5 threads (UI, A, B, C, D), can I have my method to be executed and shared by thread A, B, C, D?

Comment: AsyncTask starts and ends on the UI thread, but whatever code is in it's doInBackground() method is executed on a background thread.  What do you mean "executed and shared by" threads?

Comment: I meant that is it possible to have a method, say, `compute()` to be parallel-computed in different threads?

Comment: Multi-threading is one way, another way I have been thinking about is hardware acceleration, maybe OpenGL helps?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41780/discussion-between-david-mays-and-ching)